# Why there is no output on asking input from user in lua using sublime text

Tags: input, lua, sublimetext3, sublimetext

[On initiating this program i got no output, not even the compiler asked me for input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66EWb.png)

Comment: You should include the code in your post in text form, not in a link to an image. code in image form puts more work on the person you are looking for help from, and as a result deters them from bothering to help.

Answer (score 0):

**You're supposed to submit text, not images.**

That being said:  Your script is fine, but Sublime pipes output to the editor, but isn't a full terminal, so doesn't allow input.

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

io.write( 'Enter a number : ' )
local a = io.stdin:read('*n')

while a < 200 do
    print( 'value of a :', a )
    a = a +1
end
```

You'll have to open an actual terminal, `cd` into the relevant directory, then run your script.

`chmod +x NAME_OF_SCRIPT.lua  &&  ./NAME_OF_SCRIPT.lua`

or

`lua NAME_OF_SCRIPT.lua`